Can the TC642B drive 2 fans?
Is it possible to drive 2 identical fans with a single TC642B (datasheet)?
The mechanical design in the project imposes two small fans instead of a single big one, and I need to avoid the cost and space of duplicating the circuit. I could drop blocked-fan detection on 1 fan if necessary. I selected the simplest schematic possible of Fig. 5-2 (p9).

Option1 : connect 2 fans in parallel. The IC would sense pulses from both fans.
Option2:  use a 2nd MOSFET, so the IC would sense pulses from 1 fan only.

From chapter 3.2 !FAULT output, it seems that the IC just checks for missing pulses. As a consequence, option1 should work, wouldn't it ?
Thanks.

Which document are you referring to here for Fig. 5-2 (p9)?

The datasheet. I just edited the post to add a direct link to the datasheet.
